# Using .HTACCESS to delete files?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to use the .htaccess file to make it look like a specific url/file does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use use the [Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) for this.

```
 Redirect gone /example.html
```